# Is a Metro application installation restricted through Windows Store only?

Tags: windows, windows-8, installer, metro

I found that Windows 8 allows packaging and deploying of [Metro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29) applications and it can be installed by clicking on a ".bat" file. How will it technically be ensured that the applications can be installed through [Windows Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Store) only?

Can't the developers just host the package at a different location from where users can install it?

Comment: I'd suspect not because they are not as naive as Apple.

Comment: so is it possible to do such a thing in Iphone or Ipad.If yes,then why would app developers want to give a share of their revenue to Apple?

Comment: No its not possible on an iOS product. You don't have to want to...you are forced to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you will need a developer license or a special product key to enable 'side-loading' which is what you are describing.

Have a look at:

- *[Will Metro-style applications be able to be installed outside the market frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264451/will-metro-style-apps-be-able-to-be-installed-outside-the-market-frame)* (Stack Overflow) and
- *[How to Add and Remove Apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx)* (MSDN)